# Embed external webpage inside html without iframe/ajax

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on Phonegap application and basically I want to embedd an external webpage inside my html page, yes for me various options are available. I tried with `<iframe>` method, but I am getting below error:

> Refused to display 'https://xyz.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

Since I don't have control over the server side, loading an webpage inside an iframe is ruled out.

I also tried with ajax method:

```
       $.ajax({
          crossOrigin: true,
          url: 'https://xyz.com',
          success: function(data) {
            $( '#bodyFrame' ).html(data);
          }
        });
```

It works fine, but the biggest problem is it doesn't render CSS/Javascript, it only displays plain html.

I tried with `<link rel="import" href="https://xyz.com">` now I am getting cross-domain issue.

My question is, is there a way to display an external website inside an HTML page with correct css and js rendering (I don't have control on this part on server side) without IFrame/embed/object tags? I searched lot of questions on SO, most of them tell to use ajax but this have css issue. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Does it try to phishing? However, I think server-side technology will be more powerful to complete this task.

Comment: @sємsєм Yes correct.But the problem is I need to login to external authentication server from mobile and get the token to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you have at least few options.

1. Do like I just did for my project where I need to be able to show whole pages offline: load the HTML for that page, iterate through it (with regular expressions) to find out all resource links (JS, CSS, images) and download those (store to file system). Once downloaded, change the URL to URI of your local file on initial HTML. After that show that HTML for user. 
   Few special things to mention about this way in no particular order:

   - Implement cache of your own to speed this up.
   - Use blacklisting for URLs that you don't want to download.
   - caolan's [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) library is just great for this.
   - For CSS resources you need still to download images within it and change the links to those too.
   - Images can be converted just to [Base64](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) representation inside HTML for less callbacks to handle.
   - This way you can use the iframes.
2. This is pretty much related to first one but go through the HTML on your success callback and get all the links for JS and CSS and use technique described [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml) to reload those for you.

Here is summary of that method:

```
var fileref = document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Comment: Technical note: Had to take the last sentence out of numbered list to make the code snippet adding possible.